# A word/phrase for a day when you must be extremely cautious

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or a phrase which would mean a day when you have to be extra cautious because you know something bad might happen to you. For example:

> 1. Today is Friday the 13th - ___ (the word/phrase), so we have to exercise extreme caution. - Don't be so superstitious!
> 2. According to my horoscope, today is ____ (the word/phrase), so I'd better watch out for something bad.

Thank you!

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: At the moment, a day when we _don't_ need to be extremely cautious is the exception.

Answer (score 3):

*Beware the ides of March* is probably the best known phrase that answers to your title question. The critical reference here is the assassination / justified killing of Julius Caesar.  A seer warned him that danger would befall no later than the Ides.

Comment: This phrase cannot be used to fill in the blanks in the OP's examples of the intended use of the phrase sought. Also, the phrase is suitable only for the dangers of intentional actions of one's enemies, while the OP seems to be seeking a term that can be used for any kind of danger.

Comment: @jsw29 - I prefer a broader reading. I mean, if we want to get specific, it's a term that can only apply to Julius Caesar and the 15th of March, 44BC and to no other person on no other day in history.

Answer (score 2):

### Is it a full moon out?

As a lunatic in good company, I'm surprised no one has submitted anything related to **[a full moon](https://www.discovermagazine.com/mind/why-do-we-still-believe-in-lunacy-during-a-full-moon)**, a time when you can relegate your behavior to the tides and fear of lycanthropy.  Many people experience insomnia as a [lunar effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_effect),
and it's not uncommon when things start to go sideways to hear people exclaim, "[Must be the Moon](https://www.farmersalmanac.com/full-moons-people-crazy-12157)."

The lunar effect:

> A correlation between specific stages of the roughly 29.5-day lunar cycle and behavior and physiological changes in living beings on Earth, including humans. In some cases the purported effect may depend on external cues, such as the amount of moonlight.

Warnings are given in the same vein.  It might be confirmation bias, but weird things happen during the full moon, often coinciding with notions of triskaidekaphic events and pagan holidays like [Walpurgisnacht](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Walpurgis-Night), (only once a year on 30 April).

### Must be the Moon:

> ["Must be a full moon"](https://astrobob.areavoices.com/2008/12/11/must-be-a-full-moon/#:%7E:text=%22Must%20be%20a%20full%20moon,up%20during%20that%20particular%20phase.&text=If%20something%20unusual%20happens%20on,and%20obvious%2C%20to%20the%20event.) is an often heard phrase whenever something
> out of sorts or unexpected happens. Some even believe crime goes up
> during that particular phase. Scientists have done studies on the
> "full moon effect", and contrary to popular belief, have found no
> correlation between the moon’s phase and crime or other unusual
> behavior.

> [Blaming the full moon for strange behavior is a time-honored
> tradition.](https://www.discovermagazine.com/mind/why-do-we-still-believe-in-lunacy-during-a-full-moon) In the first century AD, the Roman philosopher Pliny
> suggested that the full moon caused more dew to form, which led to
> increased moisture in the brain, and that, he said, led to madness.

And there's a lot of [music](https://www.udiscovermusic.com/stories/songs-about-the-moon-20-essential-tracks/) to support being cautious about the waxing and waning of the moon.

Answer (score 1):

If you <strike>know</strike> think something bad might happen to you, it is ***ominous***.

> According to my horoscope, today is ***ominous***, so I'd
> better watch out for something bad.

Collins:

> ***[ominous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ominous)***
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> If you describe something as ominous, you mean that it worries you
> because it makes you think that something unpleasant is going to
> happen.
>
> The rolls of distant thunder were growing more ominous.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
> Publishers

Comment: The meaning of the word *ominous* requires that there be some **omen** involved. It is thus not clear how a particular day can be ominous, just by itself. A horoscope could tell me that there is something specific about this day that is ominous  (i.e. something that is an omen of some bad things), but it would be puzzling if it said that the day itself is ominous.